# Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found. Eclipse Oxygen 4.7 + Java9 error

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, eclipse-oxygen

I'm trying to test JDK9 (jdk-9-ea+147 version) with Eclipse Oxygen IDE.

I've installed jdk along with jre. From Eclipse Market Place I've installed Java9 Beta extension:

[image]

The problem is, when I'm trying to add new installed jre from Eclipse I get following error:

[image]

Interesting thing is that this error doesn't occur with installations of previous JDK versions:

[image]

Does anyone encounter simillar problem with Eclipse Oxygen? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Hmmmm..... both oxygen an java 9 support are currently on beta status (meaning unstable). Maybe you need to file a bug report

Answer (score 13):

I've just successfully tested JDK9 with Eclipse Oxygen IDE following the approach you detailed.

Here are the details of my installation (under Windows 10):

- I downloaded and installed Java jdk-9+181 from http://jdk.java.net/9/
- I downloaded and installed Eclipse Oxygen from  https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe
- I started Eclipse and attempted to add JRE9  (Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add...)
- I got the error reported in the OP ("Target is not a JDK root...").
- I then installed Java 9 Support (BETA) for Oxygen as detailed here: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen
- I restarted Eclipse and tried to add JRE 9 again. This time it worked fine:

[image]

- Also, see https://wiki.eclipse.org/Java9/Examples for further details.

Comment: Does this work with older versions of early-access of JDK9 (e.g. jdk-9-ea+147)?

Comment: @null Sorry, but I can't find a link to download early access builds for JDK9 any more. If you can provide one I'll try 147. But why not just try with the reference implementation (181) that I used?

Comment: This solution worked for me too. Only in this case I had to, after installing the plugin, check updates and install them (and restart again). Thanks

Answer (score 8):

I'm also faced this issue `"Target is not a JDK root. System Library was not found"` for `Java 11` and I have done some workaround and got to know, this is related to the version we are using either `eclipse` or `sprint tool suite`. So i figured out the correct version and posted below.

**`Java 9` Supports:**

- Spring Tool Suite:3.9.0
- Eclipse:Oxygen (4.7)

**`Java 10` Supports:**

- Spring Tool Suite:3.9.4
- Eclipse: Oxygen (4.7.3) and Above

**`Java 11` Supports:**

- Spring Tool Suite: 3.9.7
- Eclipse: Photon 4.8, 4.10 (officially supports)

Below are references i used:

1. [STS](https://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/v397/NewAndNoteworthy.html)
2. [Eclipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software))

Click Up Vote if this is useful for you.

Answer (score 6):

You should use Standard VM **not** standard 1.1x VM
best regards!
[se pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2aQN.png)

Comment: Why? Please add explanation.

Comment: If you use Java 1.6/1.7/1.8/1.9 then select Standard VM. Standard 1.1.x VM is for as the name suggest for old 1.1 versions. Execution Environment Description are symbolic representations of JREs e.g. you could define one for 1.7.x VM execution environment then the system could be configured to use a specific JRE to implement that execution environment e.g. 1.7.0_80.

Answer (score 5):

set the path to::  /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: This looks like a Mac answer.

Answer (score 4):

This looks like Eclipse bug [494481](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494481).

Unfortunately there is currently no fix or workaround listed for the bug.

Comment: But that bug relates to using the Mars and Neon versions of Eclipse, but the OP is using Oxygen. Also, for the bug you cite, one poster specifically stated that everything was fine when using Oxygen.

Answer (score 1):

Oxygen does not come with java9 support. You need to install the eclipse Java9 support patch from the market place https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/java-9-support-beta-oxygen to be able to use Java9 or you can update from "Help" menu bar.

Ref - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509704

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem for the latest JDK."jdk-18_windows-x64_bin.exe"
However it is resolved by installing
this eclipse
https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/epp/oxygen/R/eclipse-inst-win64.exe.

Give it a try, I hope this will work for you too!
Cheers!