# Java 9 on Mac OS X Eclipse Neon Error "Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found."

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, java-9

Is it possible to use Java 9 as an Installed JRE in eclipse on OS X (El Capitan 10.11.6)? I've installed both the Java 9 (EA build 165) JRE and JDK from the [JDK Early Access Release page](https://jdk9.java.net/download/) and I get the following error in eclipse Neon.3 (4.6.3) when I attempt to add Java 9:

**Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found.**

[image]
I found [this eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494481), but it's almost a year old at this point. Surely this has been fixed by now?

I did try installing the [Java 9 Beta Support Plugin](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.6-P-builds/) (also kinda old at this point), and that doesn't seem to work either.

(Note that I am asking about Eclipse Neon (4.6), not Eclipse Oxygen (4.7) as mentioned on [this stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029647/target-is-not-a-jdk-root-system-library-was-not-found-eclipse-oxygen-4-7-jav)).

I appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you try Eclipse Oxygen? If it does not work, then you should wait until August 2017 when Java 9 is released. So far you can use IDEA or NetBeans.

Comment: No, I didn't try Eclipse Oxygen. I prefer to use Spring STS. Thanks for the info on using IDEA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found. Eclipse Oxygen 4.7 + Java9 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029647/target-is-not-a-jdk-root-system-library-was-not-found-eclipse-oxygen-4-7-jav)

Comment: STS plugins can probably be installed into Oxygen...

Comment: I was using Eclipse Neon with this Java 9 beta plug-in, it was working older releases of Java 9 like EA build 108. Then i upgraded the JVM, I was able to run eclipse with new version, but was not longer recognized - same error as in your case. Eclipse Oxygen works fine with new versions of Java 9, the plug-in is ok.

Comment: I was able to run it with Eclipse Oxygen and the "Java 9 support plug-in". Full info can be found here https://javatutorial.net/install-java-9-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

"Target is not a JDK root. System library was not found."
The solution that worked for me with same problem in Win7 with Oxygen and jre9 was to update Eclipse.

1. Menu: Help:"Check for updates" and update.
2. Restart Eclipse.

Before i solved the problem i've changed my Eclipse.ini in Eclipse root dir to

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.X.X\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

After this line

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

It did'nt help before i updated and i'm not sure if this is needed to so i recomend all who have the same problem to first update Eclipse and test. If it still is not working change the ini arrording to mine.