# target is not a jdk root. system library was not found. in eclipse 4.8 photon + jdk-10.0.2

Tags: java, eclipse

I've tried to add JRE10 in Eclipse 4.8 Photon (Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Add...). Unfortunately I've received the following error message:
[target is not a jdk root. system library was not found.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekPq5.png)

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41029647/target-is-not-a-jdk-root-system-library-was-not-found-eclipse-oxygen-4-7-jav?noredirect=1&lq=1) and the related answers but since it is about different versions of Eclipse and JRE I wonder if somebody encountered a problem like mine and if somebody knows a solution about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is in the selected directory? Does it contain `bin/java` and `bin/javac`? If yes, what exact version is shown in the _About_ dialog?

Comment: Yes, the selected directory contains bin/java and bin/javac. The version is 10.0.2. The strange thing is that I've tried again a minute ago and this time there is no error message. Everything works fine although I haven't changed anything

Comment: Maybe at the first attempt, the JDK was not finished installed/extracted/copied. Anyway, does everything work now?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, I'm sure that the JDK was already extracted at the first attempt, because it had been done earlier.